# issues to get the Latitude using network and GPS provider

Tags: android, gps, provider

Hi I have implemented a location listener in my app which uses the Network Provider to get the GPS values. It's working fine, but now I want to get GPS using network provider and GPS provider. am trying but am getting the same value.

here my code

```
   Location networkLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    Location gpsLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

**Where i have to use networkLoc and gpsLoc?**

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double lat1 = (double) (location.getLatitude());//here i get the latitude value..how to know these values are from different provider
        double lng1= (double) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(Double.toString(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(Double.toString(lng));


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the case, that if the user has GPS Enabled your line

```
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
```

is returning `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` already, so you just query `getLastKnownLocation(provider)` twice with the same Provider. Try this instead:

```
    Location networkLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    Location gpsLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

or if you really don't care which one to use

```
List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(false);
Location[] loc = new Location[providers.size];
int i = 0;
for (String provider: providers){
    loc[i++] = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
}
```

EDIT: due to refactoring of the question

```
//query provider from Location
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
    String provider = loc.getProvider();
    if (provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        //GPS Location
    } else if (provider.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
        //Network Location
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: @Rafel each and every time i want to get both providers.how to use in onlocation changed?

Comment: Sorry I could not understand your question properly... Also note that you really should UNregister locationChanges in onPause. You could check through which provider the Location was send with `location.getProvider()`. Everything seems just fine inside your onLocationChanged

Comment: you have to use them "nowhere". Inside your last code, you registered for locationUpdates. The onLocationChanged gets invoked by the system, everytime a new Location is arriving. It may be the case that getLastKnownLocation() returns the same value, even for different providers. just wait a little until system is pushing new Locations inside you onLocationChanged Method. to find out the provier inside your onLocationChanged just ask the Location for it. I updated my answer to clearify that